# RxJava exeute multiple observables in a chain only on success

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am trying to implement the following idea.

Consider the following case

1. A user is prompted with an input field
2. If the user has entered something, another dialog appears in order to confirm the previous action
3. If the user confirmed his actions then a service is called.

It would be really elegant if this could implemented using RxJava in a chain.

Here what I tried

```
PublishSubject<String> inputSubject = ...;
PublishSubject<Boolean> confirmSubject = ...;
PublishSubject<Integer> serviceSubject = ...;
```

I need to run these subject in a chain and the next subject should be executed only if the previous one was successful and haven't returned an error.

These subject are controlled by different object and called in the ordinary manner like that

```
    dialogSubject.onNext(userInput);
    dialogSubject.onCompleted();
```

Please suggest whether it is possible to implement my idea or maybe there are better ways to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Subject** to chain the emission of one observable into another

```
@Test
public void chainObservables() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable<Long> observable = Observable.just(1l);
    Subject<Long, Long> publishSubject = ReplaySubject.create(1);
    Subject<Long, Long> publishSubject2 = ReplaySubject.create(1);
    observable.subscribe(publishSubject);
    publishSubject.subscribe(publishSubject2);
    publishSubject2.subscribe(System.out::println, (e) -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()), System.out::println);
}
```

Here observable pass the item to publishSubject and publishSubject to publishSubject2

You can see more examples of Hot observables here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/connectable/HotObservable.java